# Loading script with jquery ajax: strange behavior?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been running through some strange behavior while using the ajax script loading with jquery. When I run this page locally on my computer everything is fine, when I run it online (on DropBox) it fails to load saying (on console) a reference error: sjcl is undefined.

This is the page (with its script):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="fr"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Pack Résidanat — par @Anonyme</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></head><body>
<font face="monospace"><div id="status"></div></font>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#status").append("Chargement du décrypteur... ");
  $.ajax({
    url:"http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5tsysv6hmneaxop/foo.js",
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"script",
    success:function(data){
      $("#status").append("[OK]<br/>Chargement de la clé de cryptage... ");
      $.ajax({
        url:"http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/70d5avb1s7s7shd/crkey.js",
        type:"GET",dataType:"script",
        success:function(data){
          $("#status").append("[OK]<br/>Chargement du pack... ");
          $.ajax({
            url:"http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nxxpecpdci9gtbd/pack.js",
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"script",
            success:function(data){
              $("#status").append("[OK]<br/>Décryptage du pack...<br/>");
              $("#status").fadeOut("slow",function(){document.write(unescape(sjcl.json.decrypt(crkey,pack)));});
            },
            error:function(data){
              $("#status").append("[ERROR]<br/>Erreur lors du chargement du pack.");
            }
          });
        },
        error:function(data){
          $("#status").append("[ERROR]<br/>Erreur lors du chargement de la clé de cryptage.");
        }
      });
    },
    error:function(data){
      $("#status").append("[ERROR]<br/>Erreur lors du chargement du décrypteur.");
    }
  });
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

And this the online version: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5o3r2bfknw93h62/pack.html

The sjcl (Stanford Javascript Crypto Library http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) is defined in the foo.js file that I first loaded SUCCESSFULLY..

foo.js uses strict mode globally ("use strict").

Can you see the problem?

P.S: sorry for my bad, poor and ugly english..

**Strange part:**

When the page and the foo.js files are hosted in the same server it fails to load with jquery ajax saying "success":

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5o3r2bfknw93h62/pack.html
http://copy.com/kqIL8nF0WQjX/pack2.html

While when they are hosted in different servers it works fine (one in Dropbox and the other in Copy.com):

http://copy.com/tkGTmnJlJxS3/pack.html
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/q3cnv2qdc7vjirh/pack2.html

Any clues?

Comment: The script foo.js is not loaded in this html file. Where have you loaded that script ? Can you just try loading foo.js in the above mentioned html file

Comment: It is the first to be loaded with jquery ajax! (http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5tsysv6hmneaxop/foo.js) The script checks if this script is loaded successfully then it proceeds..

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! As I said it's an escaped string.. I'll update it so everything becomes clear to you!

Comment: You say it works locally? How do you run it locally? What changes?

Comment: Are you aware that, as used, `document.write()` will replace the whole page including the javascript environment?

Comment: acdcjunior: locally I mean running the page simply in my computer using the file:// protocole.
Beetroot-Beetroot: yes but it's not a real issue I think since I'm not using those scripts after I load the packed one.

Comment: OK, but you will lose EVERYTHING - Doctype, HTML tag, head with its title and meta tags, and the body tag. So be sure the packed version has all of these.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - that's the point, the pack file contains the complete HTML of an encrypted site.

Comment: Indeed the packed file have it all! ;)

Comment: OK, I haven't seen the packed file. Just thought I'd mention it in case it was an issue.

Comment: There's nothing to see, it's encrypted 8) ...

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with this type of script loading. So in the success handler of the first ajax call - can you see if sjcl is accessible. It should be available in data, assuming that the entire script is loaded into the data variable. Can you print out data of the first ajax call and see if it contains sjcl ?

Comment: In the success handler of the first ajax call sjcl is not available; I have a "sjcl is not defined" error and the script stops running if I try to print it.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like :

```
$(function(){
    var stat = $("#status");
    stat.append("Chargement du décrypteur... ");
    $.when(
        $.getScript("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5tsysv6hmneaxop/foo.js").fail(function() {
            stat.append("[ERROR]<br/>Erreur lors du chargement du décrypteur.");
        })
    ).then(function() {
        stat.append("[OK]<br/>Chargement de la clé de cryptage... ");
        return $.getScript( "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/70d5avb1s7s7shd/crkey.js" ).fail(function() {
            stat.append("[ERROR]<br/>Erreur lors du chargement de la clé de cryptage.");
        });
    }).then(function() {
        $("#status").append("[OK]<br/>Chargement du pack... ");
        return $.getScript( "http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nxxpecpdci9gtbd/pack.js" ).fail(function() {
            stat.append("[ERROR]<br/>Erreur lors du chargement du pack.");
        });
    }).then(function() {
        stat.append("[OK]<br/>Décryptage du pack...<br/>")
            .fadeOut("slow",function(){
                document.write( unescape( sjcl.json.decrypt(crkey,pack) ) );
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Same result (check it out here: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5o3r2bfknw93h62/pack.html)! To make things even stranger the same file works on Copy.com (a DropBox-like):  http://copy.com/tkGTmnJlJxS3/pack.html REALLY STRANGE! Same result in Chrome, Firefox and Opera..

Comment: This behavior is seen when both the page and the foo.js file are in the same domain: http://copy.com/kqIL8nF0WQjX/pack2.html have the same problem (sjcl undefined) while http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/q3cnv2qdc7vjirh/pack2.html works fine (foo.js in Copy and the page in DropBox).

Comment: How about `crkey` and `pack`, are they also undefined?

Comment: No. In Chrome/Firefox/Opera's console I get only this message "Uncaught ReferenceError: sjcl is not defined"

Comment: How about if you test `sjcl`, `crkey` and `pack` on the line before `document.write(...)`? For example, `console.log([ sjcl==undefined, crkey==undefined, pack==undefined ]);`

Comment: It does seem to work on jsFiddle -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CY6bR/), are you sure your server somehow isn't the problem ?

Comment: Beetroot-Beetroot: in http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5o3r2bfknw93h62/pack.html crkey is loaded while pack and sjcl are not loaded?! Jquery ajax had a "success" result, so how come it does not load?! Is it because both are large files?!
adeneo: that's the thing I thought about but how come crossing servers works while same server does not work on a client side application?

Comment: Could be a charset issue. If the script files are of different charset than the host page then you could get ajax success but javascript error. See the `scriptCharset` description [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). And I guess it's possible that the different servers may behave differently in this regard.

Comment: It's the same charset (utf-8) and I have the meta in html. The thing is that it works when I have the page on one server and the scripts on the other and it doesn't work when I have both the page and the scripts on the same server.

Comment: Mmmmm, whatever the problem is, it's not completely straightforward.

Comment: How to define scriptCharset? I added scriptCharset:"UTF-8" but it I got the same result: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5o3r2bfknw93h62/pack.html

Comment: And you're asbolutely sure the path and filename is typed correctly ?

Comment: `scriptCharset:"utf-8"`. I'm not sure if it's case sensitive.

Comment: adeneo, must be correct - he's getting ajax success remember.

Comment: Even with that it does not work as you can see: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5o3r2bfknw93h62/pack.html
It's about 4:38 am here in Tunisia; gotta have some sleep! lol Tomorrow I'll have a big day on this and report back.. Thank you for trying to help me out with this! The problem as you said is not straightforward; strange as I said.. If a fix is not possible I'll use the two servers instead of using one as it strangely seems to work like that..

Comment: OK, I'll keep this tab open.

Comment: I don't know if it's quite it but the foo.js uses the strict mode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) It's maybe a security restriction or something like that.. what do you think? Do I have to rewrite it all to normal mode? I'll also try to let the foo.js the last to be loaded tomorrow..

Comment: Strategy ... **use strict**: I don't think strict mode is an issue but you can try applying it differently to see if it makes a difference. Remove "use strict" from the start of the script and insert "use strict" inside every *function* - there are 74 of them, 73 are anonymous and one is named. **script size**: Replace both long scripts with something very simple with an observable outcome, eg alert("nom-de-script");

Comment: BINGO!!! I removed the all "use strict" thing and everything is going just fine! http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5o3r2bfknw93h62/pack.html
I don't fully understand what this is all about.. Any clues?
I can not answer this question I asked on Stackoverflow so if you have any ideas how things went wrong please make a proper answer so it may help anyone who is using the Stanford Javascript Cryptography Library and having a strange behavior with jquery ajax.
P.S: I'll remove the links above in 24 hours; it's a part of a "protected" project you know. :-P

Comment: Excellent, so it *was* strict mode! But even more surprising PR, is that a Tunisian who apologizes for his poor English should know to say "BINGO"!

Comment: Oh that was rich! :-P English is only my third spoken language: first comes arab, second is french.. you should not see my fourth: german, some massacre to Beethoven's language; poorer you die! XD